# Override boot function when insert function calling in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, insert, overriding

I have override boot function inside the laravel model, code structure something like this:

```
class modelName extends Model
{
        protected static function boot(){
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model){
        //Do Some Stuff
        });
}
```

This is working fine when I'm calling create a function, like this:

```
modelName::create($tmpArray);
```

But it's not working when I want to use insert function:

```
modelName::insert($tmpArray);
```

Now I want to call boot function when insert function called, I've two-dimensional array; in that case, I've only insert function to save data in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Events are only called when using the Eloquent functions to save/update/delete records.

If you want events to be triggered when saving multiple records, you could try to use `Model::createMany($arrayOfObjects)`. However, checking the source code for this function, it will actually run a separate query for each record that's in the array. So if you got a whole lot, you might need to think of a different route.

Answer (score 0):

**creating** is event of eloquent model.

insert() is not method of eloquent model, its method of db queries.

> try to use **eloquent method** instead of db query.

[see laravel doc for eloquent methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts)

[see Db queries method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts)

Comment: I've two-dimensional array; in that case, I've only insert function to save data in a single row.

Comment: You can use  Model::createMany($arrayOfObjects) method of eloquent to create multiple related models

Answer (score 0):

for two two-dimensional array can use eloquent method of **createMany or saveMany**

> difference between save and create is that save accepts a full Eloquent model instance while create accepts a plain PHP array.
>   you can refer laravel docs [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)